# ASP.NET Dynamic Data field value disappears in the browser

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I have an ASP.NET Dynamic Data web application, with an entity called `ActivationResource`.  One of the properties of this is a CellPhone field.  Now, whenever I open a List or Details view of one of these entities, the cell phone number displays for a moment then disappears.

Anyone have any ideas as to the cause of this mysterious behavior?

Comment: any code that you can share with us ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange that it would disappear after showing up.  This sounds like a client issue instead of server, since the server is out of the loop after returning the page (AJAX aside).

Things to try:

- If you View Source on the page, do you see the phone number after it disappears?
- If you write a static HTML page with a similarly formatted phone number, do you get the same behavior?
- What browser are you using, and does it happen with others?

Sometimes, browser pluggins like to mess with what they detect as phone numbers to make them do special things (e.g. I think Skype does that).